# bootstrap grid: how to achieve this mosaic result?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, grid

with the grid of bootstrap, I want to achieve the result of the joined image except that the first box has in lg and sm twice the width of the other boxes.

The grid of the image is easily replicable with 3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 but that would not allow me to have the first div twice the width.

How can I achieve this ? Thanks a lot !

precision : I need the remaining space below the first box with a double width to be filled whatever its height

EDIT : I have almost a good result using multiple col-xx-XX but then I have double paddings too.
If I remove double paddings totally, I can have some joined div. If I just keep a padding left or right for those 2, I get an extra padding in xs view

[image]

Comment: Have you looked at [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/)? It's an awesome grid layout library, that _"works by placing elements in optimal position based on available vertical space"_. If I understand your question correctly, it should be able to help you achieve what your looking for.

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this:

```
  <div class="container">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" style="background-color:red; height: 200px; margin: 15px;"></div>
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" style="background-color:blue; height: 400px; margin: 15px;"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" style="background-color:yellow; height: 300px; margin: 15px;"></div>
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" style="background-color:black; height: 300px; margin: 15px;"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" style="background-color:grey; height: 200px; margin: 15px;"></div>
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" style="background-color:green; height: 400px; margin: 15px;"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this answers your question.
https://jsfiddle.net/87LyrLcj/1/

Comment: This doesn't seem like it is a general solution. I cannot get it to create a mosaic where the divs are of arbitrary height. It seems like hights need to be exactly as specified to create a perfect mosaic.

Comment: @AndréC.Andersen at the time of answering this question I was using bootstrap 3. Please read the docs to get a better understanding. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#grid and yes you need to specify the height.

Comment: Thanks @BlakePaige, that probably explains it. My frontend dev fixed it for me, ended up with using `column-count` and `@media` in CSS to handle responsiveness.